# Dropdownlist in asp.net mvc technical working reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-helper

I have invested my few hours figuring out how to work with dropdownlists..
finally I have a working piece of code.. but I do not know how it works.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79aYSOcmpV8&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v

In Controller.

```
ViewBag.Breed = new SelectList(db.Breeds, "breed", "breed");
```

In view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Breed", "Select Breed")
```

How does it works??

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.Breed = new SelectList(db.Breeds, "breed", "breed");
```

The first parameter here is the data source of your dropdown list.
For the second parameter, you can pass it a property of your model, then it would become the value of your drop down.
The third parameter is the display text of your drop down list.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Breed", "Select Breed")
```

The first parameter is the name of your SelectList ViewBag. The second one is the default text for your dropdown list when nothing is selected yet.